# PHP Slim - No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present on the requested resource

Tags: php, cors, slim, same-origin-policy, slim-3

I'm new to Slim framework. I'm building a REST API and I'm having problems implementing CORS.

First I went along with the example from the 
[Slim cookbook](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/cookbook/enable-cors.html):

Then I used [/tuupola/cors-middleware](https://github.com/tuupola/cors-middleware) :

I came up with this:

```
$app->options('/{routes:.+}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    return $response;
});

$app->add(new Tuupola\Middleware\CorsMiddleware([
    "origin" => ["*"],
    "methods" => ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE"],
    "headers.allow" => [],
    "headers.expose" => [],
    "credentials" => false,
    "cache" => 0,
]));
```

The problem is with routes that have a placeholder argument. For example:

```
$app->get('/items', 'ItemsController:index');
$app->get('/items/{id}', 'ItemsController:getItem');
```

The response from **/items** has a 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' header, but the one from **/items/{id}** does not and this results in errors (CORS policy).
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the '/items/{id}' response? Is it 200 OK or is instead some 4xx or 5xx error response?

Comment: GET: HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I caused the problem myself, it's not a Slim issue.
I created a temporary error handler method with this code:

```
$json = array("error" => [
    "message" => $message,
    "code"    => $code
]);

exit(json_encode($json));
```

Simply setting a header solves the issue:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Comment: where you set this ?

Comment: Sorry @duardbr for answering so late. The header function should be called before the exit.